# Can not read more than 32 blocks in a single READ MULTIPLE BLOCKS command from M24LR

Tags: tags, nfc, rfid, iso-15693

I am trying to read multiple blocks (all of them in a single READ MULTIPLE BLOCKS command) from a [M24LR](https://www.st.com/en/nfc/m24lr-series-dynamic-nfc-tags.html?querycriteria=productId=SS851) chip through NFC-V.

```
let writeData = new Uint8Array(5);
writeData[0] = 0x0A; // Flags
writeData[1] = 0x23; // Read multiple block
writeData[2] = 0x00; // Address of starting block (first 8bit) 
writeData[3] = 0x00; // Address (second 8bit)
writeData[4] = 0x1F; // Numbers of block (0x20 is not working)
nfc.transceive(writeData.buffer)
  .then(response => {
    console.log('response: ' + response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('error transceive: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
  });
```

If I am asking for 32 blocks it works well, if I ask for 33 blocks, the command fails with an error.

Is it something that I am doing wrong? Does the READ MULTIPLE BLOCKS command have a limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the datasheet ([*M24LR64-R: Dynamic NFC/RFID tag IC with 64-Kbit EEPROM
with I²C bus and ISO 15693 RF interface*, DocID15170 Rev 16, section 26.5](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/m24lr64-r.pdf); the same also applies to [M24LR64E-R](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/m24lr64e-r.pdf), [M24LR16E-R](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/m24lr16e-r.pdf), and [M24LR04E-R](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/m24lr04e-r.pdf)):

> The maximum number of blocks is fixed at 32 assuming that they are all located in the same sector. If the number of blocks overlaps sectors, the M24LR64-R returns an error code.

Thus, the READ MULTIPLE BLOCKS command for these chips is limited to 32 blocks.

Comment: Thank you Roland. So if I want to get more than 32 blocks, is it a good practice to create a loop (for each 32 blocks) and sending multiple time the transceive command?

Comment: Yes, that's the only way to get around that limitation.